# Showing boundedness of $f(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show that the set $k=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2+e^{xy}=5\}$ is bounded? I've simply got no idea how to go on with $2$-dimensional functions..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$e^{xy} > 0$ for any real $x$, $y$. Therefore $x^2+y^2<5$, which means that all points $x,y$ lie within a circle of radius $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: This seems to be the simplest (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Note that $|x|>3$ implies $x^2+y^2+e^{xy}> 9+0+0>5$, for example.

Comment: is there any possiblity of using partial derivatives in order to show the boundedness?